# A phrase structure tree problem.... "All the faith he had had

Tags: phrases

I am trying to create a phrase structure tree for the sentence

> All the faith he had had had had no effect on the outcome of his life.

Many people are familiar with this sentence I am sure. The verb phrase I understand, but what about "he had had?" "All the faith" is the noun phrase Det-Det-N, but what about the rest of the noun phrase? What is "he had had" and how can I write this into my phrase structure tree?

Comment: It's *All the faith* [that] *he had had*.  You have a reduced relative clause modifying *faith*.  The subject of the relative clause is *he*, and the verb is the past perfect of *to have*, namely *had had*.  Does that help or hurt?

Answer (score 1):

**[** All the faith [he had had] **]**

The inner bracketed element (*he had had*) is a relative clause modifying and combining with "faith", to give the noun phrase *All the faith* (*that*) *he had had*.

Within the relative clause, "he" is subject, "had had" the verb string, and the noun "faith" is the object of the second "had".